# C/C++ - What is the purpose of colon in uint8_t x:6

Tags: c

Apologies if this is a basic question but I'm seeing these colons (`:`) for the first time in the definition of the `struct`. What do these colons do?

```
struct gsm48_meas_res {
    uint8_t rxlev_full:6,
         dtx_used:1,
         ba_used:1;
    uint8_t rxlev_sub:6,
         meas_valid:1,
         spare:1;
    uint8_t no_nc_n_hi:1,
         rxqual_sub:3,
         rxqual_full:3,
         spare2:1;
    uint8_t rxlev_nc1:6,
         no_nc_n_lo:2;
    uint8_t bsic_nc1_hi:3,
         bcch_f_nc1:5;
    uint8_t rxlev_nc2_hi:5,
         bsic_nc1_lo:3;
    uint8_t bsic_nc2_hi:2,
         bcch_f_nc2:5,
         rxlev_nc2_lo:1;
    uint8_t rxlev_nc3_hi:4,
         bsic_nc2_lo:4;
    uint8_t bsic_nc3_hi:1,
         bcch_f_nc3:5,
         rxlev_nc3_lo:2;
    uint8_t rxlev_nc4_hi:3,
         bsic_nc3_lo:5;
    uint8_t bcch_f_nc4:5,
         rxlev_nc4_lo:3;
    uint8_t rxlev_nc5_hi:2,
         bsic_nc4:6;
    uint8_t bcch_f_nc5_hi:4,
         rxlev_nc5_lo:4;
    uint8_t rxlev_nc6_hi:1,
         bsic_nc5:6,
         bcch_f_nc5_lo:1;
    uint8_t bcch_f_nc6_hi:3,
         rxlev_nc6_lo:5;
    uint8_t bsic_nc6:6,
         bcch_f_nc6_lo:2;
} __attribute__ ((packed));
```

I am facing some problems in assigning values to these `uint8_t` variables. Initially I thought it is the default assignment but after exhausting all other possibilities, I think it has something to do with these colons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit-field, which is something very poorly regulated by any standard. For example

```
uint8_t rxlev_full:6,
         dtx_used:1,
         ba_used:1;
```

means "somewhere in the memory, give me 6 bits then 1 bit then 1 bit". You cannot know or assume the bit order portably - it is compiler-specific. Also, standard bit-fields are only defined for `_Bool`, `signed int` and `unsigned int`. Using `uint8_t` is a non-standard extension.

So there is no telling what this code will actually do. You have to read your compiler manual to know the specifics.